# Why layout is not attach in RecyclerView Adapter class?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-recyclerview

I have the following setup for a recyclerview.

Now the problem is my layout is not attached with the recyclerview adapter, meaning it is not showing when I enter the layout name in the recyclerview adapter class.

**fragment_service.xml**

```xml
<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/viewPager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="150dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp" />

    <include
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        layout="@layout/layout1" />

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recycler_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:scrollbars="horizontal" />

</LinearLayout>
```

**list_view_item.xml**

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:weightSum="4">

    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="0dp"
       android:layout_weight="0.7"
       xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
       card_view:cardBackgroundColor="#EEEBEB"
       card_view:cardElevation="2dp"
       android:layout_margin="5dp"
       card_view:cardUseCompatPadding="false">

    <LinearLayout
        android:weightSum="2.5"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/title"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="0.5"
            android:text="Textview"/>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1.5"
            android:weightSum="4"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/iv1"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:src="@drawable/btn_plumbing_services"
                />
            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/iv2"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:src="@drawable/btn_plumbing_services"
                />
            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/iv3"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:src="@drawable/btn_plumbing_services"
                />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/iv4"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:src="@drawable/btn_plumbing_services"
                />

        </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="0.5"
        android:weightSum="4"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv1"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="TextView"/>
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv2"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="TextView"/>
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv3"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="TextView"/>
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv4"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="TextView"/>

    </LinearLayout>


    </LinearLayout>


  </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

</LinearLayout>
```

**listFragServiceAdapter.java**

```java
    public class listFragServiceAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter {

    private List<listItems> serviceList;

    public class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
        public TextView title,tv1,tv2,tv3,tv4;
        public ImageView iv1,iv2,iv3,iv4;

        public MyViewHolder(View view){
            super(view);
        }

    }

    public listFragServiceAdapter(List<listItems> serviceList) {
        this.serviceList = serviceList;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {

        View itemView = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.list_view_item, viewGroup, false);

        return new MyViewHolder(itemView);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, int i) {

    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return 0;
    }
}
```

The main problem in the following part of the code, In second line `list_view_item` layout is not inflated. Even I can't enter the layout name.I don't know why?

```java
public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {

        View itemView = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.list_view_item, viewGroup, false);

        return new MyViewHolder(itemView);
    }
```

Comment: Can you explain better?  What does it mean: In second line list_view_item layout is not inflate ?

Comment: @GabrieleMariotti I can't enter the layout name in adapter class. If I write it gives me a error. I can't attach my layout with adapter class

Comment: @MuhammadTalmeez does following answer fix your problem? If not let me know what's the issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Update:**

Since there is no autocomplete for item layout, probable causes with fixes

- item layout not located in the `res > layout` : **Fix** - move the item layout to `res > layout`
- If file is in right location, then Android Studio/InteliJ not picking up the file: **Fix** -  Go to `File > Invalidate Caches/Restart...` and click `Invalidate and Restart` in the dialog.

---

Reason for item layout not being inflated because you `return 0;` in `getItemCount` method.

> ```
> @Override
> public int getItemCount() {
>     return 0;
> }
> ```

In order to fix this set item count to size of the `serviceList`.

```
@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return serviceList.size();
}
```

Comment: No, these changes not solve the problem. The main problem is list_view_item is not accessed in Adapter class.

Comment: @MuhammadTalmeez what you mean by not accessed in the adapter class?

Comment: mean I can't enter the layout name. It is not showing when I enter the layout name.

Comment: that means auto complete is not available?

Comment: in which directory the item layout is located?

Comment: @MuhammadTalmeez update the answer see how to fix autocomplete issue

Comment: directory is same.

Comment: @MuhammadTalmeez then try the second step in the answer

Comment: Unbelievable problem is solved. Thank you very much.

Comment: my pleasure. Actually those weird errors are common with AS. common solutions to weird problems that you might face is. Invalidate cache and restart, Rebuild, Clean project.